# Is there a global variable that is set when Playwright is running tests?

Tags: playwright

I want to be able to branch my code when Playwright is running tests. Is there a variable that is available? I have tried `playwright`.

(the reason I want to branch my code is because urql cache exchange doesn't play nicely with Playwright)

Comment: I am not able to understand what do you mean by `branch my code` here?

Comment: `if (playwrightIsRunning) { doA() } else { doB() }`

Comment: What is the use case here? Can you provide more specifics of your scenario where you need this functionality?

Comment: There might be other better ways to achieve the same goal.

Comment: I got around the problem by explicitly setting an environment variable before running my tests.